# How do I add env variables to an aws ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, mern, ec2-ami

A total beginner level question here - I am trying to deploy my mern full stack app to aws ec2 (Amazon Linux 2 ) as a side project for the first time. I was able to get the frontend static React files into the aws ec2 instance. But I am confused as to how to proceed with the backend portion. The backend (nodejs + express) uses a .env file for database connections and such. What would be the safest and/or conventional method to transfer the values in the env file to the instance?

Here are the suggestions I came across and my thoughts on them. Would appreciate some guidance.

1. Since the instance platform is a Linux, I could add the variables to the .bash_profile - seems like the relatively safest and easiest option (as this is a small-scale side project app). Would the env data be immediately accessible to the backend files? or are there other steps to take afterwards? Will the vars stay afer I end the terminal session?
2. Upload the env files along with the other backend file in to the instance - does not seem safe as the env file data is in clear text format and may be easily accessible
3. Add the env data as 'user data' of the instance - safer than option 2 but how would I run the user data? (the [aws website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-add-user-data.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console) mentions it does not run automatically)
4. Look into AWS SDKs or AWS Parameter Store

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `.env` file in the existing server, option 2 (storing it as `.env` file in EC2) is the direct equivalent. This is a valid and secure design, as long as the file does not contain any secret values.

If your variables *do* have secrets, this is another problem altogether. The "AWS way" would be SSM Parameter Store or Secrets Manager. I don't see how storing it in user data or `.bash_profile` makes it more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be that you store your .env to secure `S3` storage bucket and add shell commands in `start_server.sh` for retrieving `.env` from S3 and load it with your application to work.

Still, I am not sure if this is the best or most secure  way of doing this.